# Why not raw type, static variable in generic class?

Tags: java, generics

Why not raw type, static variable in generic class?

Example,

```
  public class MyType<E> {
    class Inner { }
    static class Nested { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyType mt;          // warning: MyType is a raw type
        MyType.Inner inn;   // warning: MyType.Inner is a raw type

        MyType.Nested nest; // no warning: not parameterized type
        MyType<Object> mt1; // no warning: type parameter given
        MyType<?> mt2;      // no warning: type parameter given (wildcard OK!)
    }
}
```

`MyType` is generic class, and `Nested` is `static` class.

called `MyType.Inner`, not warning generic type.

I wonder why `static` variable is not warning raw type?

Comment: Try `MyType<?>.Nested nest2;` and you wil get the compile error 'error: cannot select a static class from a parameterized type'.

Answer (score 4):

"It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic class C anywhere in:

- the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1)".

8.5.1 refers to static nested classes.

(JLS §8.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2

So a static nested class doesn't and can't have any generic information associated with it from the outer class, so no warning about its absence.

Answer (score 2):

Because the static nested class `Nested` isn't associated with any specific instance of `MyType`. The generic types are applied (at compile-time only) to the instances you create of `MyType`, and since `Inner` is associated with such instances, it could refer to the generic parameter `E`, but `Nested` has no such connection.

Comment: +1 can you also provide JLS reference or any such reference that explains such working in depth.

Comment: @NarendraPathai See EJP's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of type erasure, Java generics can only apply to a reference to an instance of a class.

Therefore, generic parameters are not inherited at all in nested static classes.